# Suppress `.AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce` cookie for Auth Code Flow redirects [OpenIdDict]

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect, openiddict

*OpenIdDict* generates `nonce` and passes it in the query string and cookie in the Auth Code Flow redirects.

**Is there a way to constraint `nonce` to the URL only and don't generate `.AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce` cookie?**

Alternatively, is there a way to control the content of the `nonce`?

**The issue**

On a successful authentication by an OIDC Provider (Azure AD in my case), the user gets redirected from `login.microsoftonline.com` to `/signin-oidc` route of my site with the requested `id_token` (in the body of the POST request) with a request like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://XXX/signin-oidc' \
--header 'Cookie: .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.CfDCfDCfDCf_CfDCfDCfDCfDCfDCfDCfDCfD4OW_-CfDCfD7-CfDC_DCfDCfDCfDCfDQ7--CfDCfDCfDCfDCfDCfDCfDCfDCfDCfD-CfDCfDCfDCfDTn2k=N; .AspNetCore.Correlation.Fb5hJ9Fb5hJ9Fb5hJ9Fb5hJ9Fb5hJ9Fb5hJ9Fb5hJ9M=N; .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.CfDJ8N03U6q_VLVCroIelZu4xoU4Vp044l5-HBKI=N; .AspNetCore.Correlation.RZsywwRZsywwRZsywwRZsyww-7O1kKS7O1kKS7O1kKS=N; _clck=1RvTbYz|1|a8h|0' \
--header 'Origin: https://login.microsoftonline.com' \
--data-urlencode 'id_token={MY_ID_TOKEN}' \
--data-urlencode 'client_info={CLIENT_INFO}' \
--data-urlencode 'state={STATE}' \
--data-urlencode 'session_state={GUID}'
```

There's a 5% chance of the request being blocked by [WAF Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/afds-overview) (the `/signin-oidc` requests), as it has a header `Cookie` that contains a dash (`-`) symbol.

The issue may sound ridiculous, but changing the header name or removing the dash from its value makes it work.